# AC:R Waiting for Players multiplayer glitch

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

Sometimes when I end up being the first player listed in the lobby screen, the game will be stuck in the lobby "Waiting for Players". This happens even though there's more than 6 players ready to play.

Is there a trick to bypass it, since I don't think I've encountered that in other people's lobby?

Comment: No, you'll have to leave the game and join a different one.  The 1.02 patch may have fixed it.  Did you update?

Comment: The 1.02 patch is the DLC maps with 2 day trial right? Yup I already updated that one. Leaving is a real shame because sometimes there's the most awesome people in the game, argg. :(

Comment: This is definitely a bug. You should contact Ubisoft and tell them about the problem. They might be able to help you.